# On $\mathbb{E}_{n-k}$-monoidal structures on $\mathbb{E}_{n-m}$-algebras in $\mathbb{E}_{n}$-monoidal $\infty$-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories, higher-algebra

For ordinary categories, the assignment $\mathcal{C}\mapsto\mathsf{Mon}(\mathcal{C})$ defines a functor $\mathsf{Mon}\colon\mathsf{Alg}_{\mathbb{E}_{k}}(\mathsf{Cats})\to\mathsf{Alg}_{\mathbb{E}_{k-1}}(\mathsf{Cats})$, which is to say that:

- If $\mathcal{C}$ is monoidal ($\mathbb{E}_{1}$), then $\mathsf{Mon}(\mathcal{C})$ exists;
- If $\mathcal{C}$ is braided ($\mathbb{E}_{2}$), then $\mathsf{Mon}(\mathcal{C})$ is a monoidal category ($\mathbb{E}_{1}$) in two different ways, related by replacing $\beta_{A,B}$ by $\beta^{-1}_{B,A}$;¹
- If $\mathcal{C}$ is symmetric ($\mathbb{E}_{3}=\mathbb{E}_{4}=\cdots$), then $\mathsf{Mon}(\mathcal{C})$ is braided ($\mathbb{E}_{2}$), and also symmetric ($\mathbb{E}_{3}$), since $\mathbb{E}_{3}=\mathbb{E}_{4}=\cdots$.

Morevoer, if one replaces $\mathsf{Mon}(\mathcal{C})$ by $\mathsf{CMon}(\mathcal{C})$ (i.e. $\mathsf{Alg}_{\mathbb{E}_{1}}(\mathcal{C})$ by $\mathsf{Alg}_{\mathbb{E}_{2}}(\mathcal{C})\cong\mathsf{Alg}_{\mathbb{E}_{3}}(\mathcal{C})\cong\cdots$), then $\mathsf{CMon}(\mathcal{C})$ is still monoidal ($\mathbb{E}_{1}$... and braided ($\mathbb{E}_{2}$) and symmetric ($\mathbb{E}_{3}$)) when $\mathcal{C}$ is symmetric ($\mathbb{E}_{3}$... as again $\mathbb{E}_{3}=\mathbb{E}_{4}=\cdots$), but having $\mathcal{C}$ be braided fails to endow $\mathsf{CMon}(\mathcal{C})$ with a monoidal structure. So now the assignment $\mathcal{C}\mapsto\mathsf{CMon}(\mathcal{C})$ gives a functor $\mathsf{CMon}\colon\mathsf{Alg}_{\mathbb{E}_{k}}(\mathsf{Cats})\to\mathsf{Alg}_{\mathbb{E}_{k-2}}(\mathsf{Cats})$.

This whole situation made me wonder what happens in the $\infty$-setting, where now we have not only monoidal, braided, and symmetric structures, but the whole array of $\mathbb{E}_{k}$-monoidal structures for $1\leq k\leq\infty$, starting with $\mathbb{E}_{1}$ (i.e. monoidal $\infty$-categories) all the way up to $\mathbb{E}_{\infty}$ (i.e. symmetric monoidal $\infty$-categories):

- Given an $\mathbb{E}_{n}$-monoidal $\infty$-category $\mathcal{C}$, is there a sensible way to "count" how many natural induced $\mathbb{E}_{n-k}$-structures are there on $\mathsf{Alg}_{\mathbb{E}_{n-m}}(\mathcal{C})$, where $1\leq k,m\leq n-1$?
- Does the "space" of these induced structures have some kind of symmetry, such as in the case mentioned above where having a braided monoidal structure on $\mathcal{C}$ gave $\mathsf{Mon}(\mathcal{C})$ two different monoidal structures related by exchanging $\beta_{A,B}$ with $\beta^{-1}_{B,A}$?

---

¹This was pointed out by Amar Hadzihasanovic on [Zulip](https://categorytheory.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/229136-theory.3A-category.20theory/topic/commutative.20monoids.20in.20a.20braided.20monoidal.20cat) in reply to a question of David Roberts.

Comment: I think there are two separate things going on: (i) If C is E_n-monoidal then Alg_{E_k}(C) has a *canonical* E_{n-k}-monoidal structure (it can be characterized by a universal property- see HA.3.4.2.3), (ii) if D is any E_m-monoidal infty-category, then any element in the orthogonal group O(m) gives a way to alter the E_m-monoidal structure to a new one (coming from the action of O(m) on the E_m-operad itself). (So this applies when D=Alg_{E_k}(C) and m=n-k as well).